# Extract month from date field in a view

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird-2.0

I want to create a view with a date field which extract month from another date field.
I saw a lot of functions that can do with a date in parameter but I want to do with a date field.

```
create view V_statmag
as
select CODP ,
FLJMA ,
DTJOUR extract(month FROM DTJOUR) as dt_month,
NBCLIENT ,
NBORDER 
FROM DSTATMAG
```

This will allow me to filter the data according to the chosen month.

I have this error:

> Message: isc_dsql_prepare failed
>
> SQL Message : -104
> Invalid token
>
> Engine Code    : 335544569
> Engine Message :
> Dynamic SQL Error
> SQL error code = -104
> Token unknown - line 5, column 10
> extract

Comment: what's  the question?  .. you have error?   . show the error message... wrong result ? show your actual result and the expected  one

Comment: `DTJOUR extract(month FROM DTJOUR) FROM DSTATMAG,` should be `extract(month FROM DTJOUR) as dt_month,` I guess

Comment: I have tried extract(month FROM DTJOUR) as dt_month but I have an error too

Comment: Which Firebird version are you using?

Comment: I have Firebird v2.0

Comment: `but I have an error too` - but that was another error

Comment: I have the same error with `extract(month FROM DTJOUR) as dt_month`

Comment: Show the exact statement, in whole. Unless you opened some really old database (ODS 9 Interbase 5.x format) the EXTRACT function should be present even in the ancient Firebird 0.9. Thus you make some SQL error before or after that part.

Comment: `NBORDER , FROM` - what does that comma mean there? Most probably you still get DIFFERENT error message, this time about "from" keyword not about "extract" keyword

Comment: I can do like that but it's not clean at all : Create a field for each month and do this for each other `select dtjour
from DSTATMAG 
where extract(month from dtjour) = 1`

Comment: That last comment makes no sense at all. What do you mean?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line

```
DTJOUR extract(month FROM DTJOUR) FROM DSTATMAG,
```

a komma is missing between "DTJOUR" and "extract".

Comment: `FROM DSTATMAG` is also invalid

Comment: So is `NBORDER , FROM`.... That is not a real SQL statement he copies from his program, but rather a some ad hoc demonstration he tried to key into Stack Overflow, and making some unpredictable mistakes in process...

Comment: I can do like that but it's not clean at all : Create a field for each month and do this for each other `select dtjour
from DSTATMAG 
where extract(month from dtjour) = 1`

Answer (score 0):

`DTJOUR extract(month FROM DTJOUR)`

`DTJOUR` is one part of expression.
`extract(...)` is another part of expression.

But multiple parts of the expression are to be connected with some operator for the calculation.

What you are trying to do - let's assume the month being February - is making an expression `DTJOUR 2`.

That is a wrong formula. You can have `DTJOUR + 2` or `DTJOUR - 2`, or `DTJOUR * 2` - but there should be some linking operator when you try to make an expression. `DTJOUR 2` without operator just makes no sense.

You give two distinct values to the firebird's internal calculator, you demand it to combine them and to give you only one value on return, but you do not give any law how exactly should the calculator combine those two values.

Make a correct expression: either specify some operator - a law of combining two values into one, or remove one of those values.

https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-commons-expressions.html